# How to make CSS border show on radio button click

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to have a border show up around the image next to the radio button, when that radio button is clicked.  Currently, my CSS selector knowledge is lacking and I do not get the expected result.

My expectation is that when I click a radio button , the corresponding image should be highlighted, but it is not...

What is wrong?

```css
label>img ~ .input:checked  {
 border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>

    <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png"><br />
 <input type="radio" name="page" value="original" />Original </label>
</td>
<td><label>
    <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png"><br />
 <input type="radio" name="page" value="standard" checked="checked">Standard
</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Answers so far rearrange HTML elements, which is not desirable from design point of view. I prefer to keep the text at the bottom of the image, not above.  I'll re-accept if there is an answer that keeps html elements in order ...

Comment: i added the sweetbel solution for your task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution who sweets your needs :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jred10v7/)**

```
input:checked ~ img  {
    border: 2px solid #f00;

}

label, img {
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
}

label, input[type=radio] {

  top: 60px;  
}
```

HTML :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="original" /> Original<br />
        <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png">
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="standard" checked="checked"> Standard<br />
        <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png">
    </label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `input` instead of `.input` because the dot addresses a class and you have not specified a class. Additionally, the `:checked` pseudo-class needs to be written before the element you want to change. The sibling selector `~` should work in theory but I had to re-arrange the html elements. Tested using Chrome, Opera and Firefox.

```css
input:checked ~ img  {
 border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="original" /> Original<br />
        <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png">
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="standard" checked="checked"> Standard<br />
        <img src="http://bighappyface.com/Happy%20Face%2050x50.png">
    </label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that's great and it works, but it does change the visual.  This will work for me for now, but ideally I'd like to keep the radio button below the image, if possible.  What I have done now is move the text below the image, and left the radio button to be first.  Not exactly what I was going for, but it looks better for me

Answer (score 0):

fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/abasnet/0535aymy/

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}



<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="original" />Original
        <img src="http://idzyanamohddahlan.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/2472566_f520.jpg">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="page" value="standard" checked="checked">Standard
        <img src="http://idzyanamohddahlan.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/2472566_f520.jpg">
    </td>
</tr>
```